# Swift 4: Push TableViewController or CollectionViewController of Suggestions Upon Selecting UISearchBar

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, push, uisearchbar

I have a collectionViewController with a section header that contains a searchBar. (e.g. the searchBar is nested inside the section header)

I would like to present another collectionViewController UPON selecting the searchBar that appears and stops under the searchBar. I would like to use this newVC to display the updating results as you type the search.

this is what I would like it to looks like:
[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9FeW.png)

my first methodology was to copy the whole collectionView appearance (create a replicaCollectionView) and push the replicaCollectionView and simply just change the appearance of the replicas collectionView cells to look like the only thing that popped up was the new cells while the searchBar and header wouldn't change at all.(It actually looked pretty good, and it looked like a new collectionView popped up underneath it)

in my custom collectionViewHeader, I call a completion block so that I can call the function from my viewController my code looks like this:

```
class HomeControllerHeader: UICollectionViewCell, UISearchBarDelegate {
...
func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {

    completion?()
    return true
}
}
```

and in my HomeViewController:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: headerId, for: indexPath) as! HomeControllerHeader

    header.completion = {
        //pull up tableView/collectionViewController up to searchBar
    }
    return header
}
```

one of the problems that I experienced was that every time I pressed cancel on the replicaCollectionViewController, it would POP the replicaCollectionViewController and flicker, and think that the searchBar was still selected and immediately call the completion block again and re-push the newVC. This resulted in never getting rid of the replica collectionViewController (e.g. newVC)

I tried for the life of me to turn off searchBar.endEditting = true, but it would always push the replicaCollectionViewController back open before the endEditting code would run.

I could tell the previous view controller (originalCollectionView) to call searchBar.endEditting(true) in viewDidAppear but it would execute the pop before viewDidAppear and immediately returning back to replicaVC

Thanks for any help, as I know there is a better way to do this...

Comment: This question may have already been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40009046/how-to-have-a-searchbar-which-shows-suggestions-with-different-uitableview

Comment: Wow thats exactly it! Thanks!